# How to make a develop env by using singularity+vscode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, ssh, singularity-container

I created a singularity image for arm development. I installed a singularity in my WSL.
I am going to code and debug at wsl,then move it to arm platform by using Cross compiler in my singularity.
How to use vscode to build my program (arm version)? Or how to use singularity integratly with vscode?

I tried to build my program with singularity shell,and it succeed.I have learnt something about vscode's task and launch,and build my program with wsl,but I dont know how to use them to bootup a singularity and then build my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Visual Studio Code (VSCode) to build your program for the ARM platform using a Singularity image, you will need to configure the tasks and launch settings in VSCode.

First, you will need to create a **tasks.json** file in the **.vscode** folder in your project directory. This file will define the command to run the build process using Singularity. The command would look something like this:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "singularity exec /path/to/your/image.sif arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o main main.c",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You will also need to configure the launch settings in **launch.json**. This file is used to configure how your program is executed. You can use the **preLaunchTask** field to specify the build task you created above, so that it runs before your program is launched:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "preLaunchTask": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

Once you have configured the tasks and launch settings, you should be able to use the **Tasks: Run Build Task** command in VSCode to build your program using the Singularity image and the Cross compiler, and use the **Debug: Start Debugging** command to run and debug your program.

You can also use the **vscode-singularity** extension, which is a Singularity extension for VSCode. It allows you to manage Singularity images, containers and shells directly from VSCode.